# Regex for parsing Wikicode in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I try to parse articles from wikipedia. I use the *page-articles.xml file, where they backup all their articles in a wikicode-format. To strip the format and get the raw text, I try to use Regular Expressions, but I am not very used to it. I use C# as programming language.
I tried a bit around with Expresso, a designer for Regular Expressions, but I am at the end of my wits. Here is what I want to achieve:

The text can contain the following structures:
[[TextN]] or
[[Text1|TextN]] or 
[[Text1|Text2|...|TextN]]

the [[ .... ]] pattern can appear within the Texti aswell. I want to replace these structure with TextN

For identifing the structures withhin the text I tried the following RegEx:

```
\[\[ ( .* \|?)* \]\]
```

Expresso seems to run and endless loop with this one. After 5 minutes for a relative small text, I canceled the Test Run.

Then I tried something more simple, I want to capture anything between the brackets:

```
\[\[ .* \]\]
```

but when I have a line like:

```
[[Word1]] text inbetween [[Word2]]
```

the expression returns the whole line, not

[[Word1]]

[[Word2]]

Any tips from Regex-Experts here to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\[\[(.*?\]\]` would do it.

The key is the .*? which means get any characters but as few a possible.

EDIT

For nested tags one approach would be:

```
\[\[(?<text>(?>\[\[(?<Level>)|\]\](?<-Level>)|(?! \[\[ | \]\] ).)+(?(Level)(?!)))\]\]
```

This ensures that the [[ and ]] match across the text as well.

Comment: Will fail on nested tags: [[This is a [[NestedTag]].]]

Comment: As SealedSun points out, I need an RegEx that can deal with nested tags.

Comment: How do you want to deal with the nested tags? What do you want to do with the nested tag? Treat is separately or just remove the nested brackets?

Comment: Many thanks Lazarus! This RegEx handles the nested tags properly! I want to treat nested tags the same way as stated above. So from "[[Text11 | Text12 | [[Text21 | Text22]] Text13]]" I need "Text22 Text13" as the result. Always the last item of a list separeted by |. If that would be possible with a regex too, that would be nice, but getting this by hand isn't that much of a problem with the result of your regex above.

Comment: After checking the results from your Regex, I think the replacement of the inner tags won't be nessecary, because it seems, that they only occur in tags, that will be removed anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use regular expressions (since they don't handle recursion/nesting well).

Instead I would parse the text *by hand**, which isn't particularly difficult in this case.

You could represent the text as a stream of **elements** whereas each **element** is either

- a plain text **chunk**, or
- a **tag**

A **tag** might contain multiple **element streams**, separated by `|`.

```
elementStream ::= element*
element ::= chunk | tag
chunk ::= TEXT
tag ::= "[[" elementStream otherStreams "]]"
otherStreams ::= "|" elementStream otherStreams
```

Your parser could represent each of those definitions with a method. So you'd have an `elementStream` method that would call `element` as long as there is text available and the next two characters are not "]]" or "|" (if you are inside a tag).
Each call to `element` would return the element parsed, either a chunk or a tag. etc.

This would essentially be a **recursive descent parser**. 
Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser (the article is rather long/complicated, unfortunately)

Comment: Yap, I think pasing by hand will be the one. I do not really understand the method your are suggesting yet, but I just spend one or two brain cells on it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Wikipedia page I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because regular expressions tries to find always the longest matches possible. You should change `.*`

Try using

```
\[\[([A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d+]*)(\|\1)*\]\]
```

This will match only letters, `|` sign and numbers in double brackets + it checks if value starts with the letter.

Comment: Won't work since aaginor expects tags to be nested: [[Tag1|[[Tag2]]|Tag3]]

Comment: As SealedSun points out, I need en RegEx that can deal with nested tags.

Comment: Regex does not handle nesting/recursion very well.

Answer (score 0):

If Expresso isn't working out for you, you may want to try [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

While not free, it does provide an excellent real time testing environment where you can see how your regex is going to match a section of sample text.

Answer (score 0):

If GPL2 is not an issue for you, maybe you could check out the source code of [Screwturn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/) and see how an expert does it. It's in C#, BTW

Comment: I took a glimpse at the code. He uses Regex, but his also doesn't deal with nested tags.